# Why are C# number types immutable?

Tags: c#, types, immutability

Why are `int`s and `double`s immutable? What is the purpose of returning a new object each time you want to change the value?

The reason I ask is because I'm making a class: `BoundedInt`, which has a value and an upper and lower bound. So I was wondering: should I make this type immutable too? (Or should it be a `struct`?)

Comment: You open huge cans of worms with these questions.  My recommendation is to think twice about trying to push your data validation into the data itself.  The validation makes more sense at a higher level of abstraction than the underlying datatypes.  For example, you may need to have one piece of data range bound by the value of another piece of data.

Comment: @Merlyn: What about data with implicit boundaries, like a length [0, ∞), an angle [0, 360), or the result of a dice roll [1,6]? I certainly don't want to be -180cm tall.

Comment: @Seth: These are special cases that do not define our architecture. Whether a value of 361 or -1 is invalid depends entirely on what they are interpreted as, not on the values in and of themselves.

Comment: @Seth: A default constraint bound to a type can be useful (e.g., a 6-sided die), but you'll very often want to customize that constraint.  Units are a related concern.  A better approach is to use a constraint solving/mapping system, or a contract-based-programming framework (e.g. spec#).

Comment: you need to listen Uncle Bob's discussion on DotNetRocks about 'future of OOP'

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Firstly:

> What is the purpose of returning a new object each time you want to change the value?

I think you might be mistaken about how value types work. This isn't some costly operation like you may be imagining; it's simply the overwriting of data (as opposed to, e.g., dynamic allocation of new memory).

Secondly: here's a very simple example of why numbers are immutable:

```
5.Increase(1);
Console.WriteLine(5); // What should happen here?
```

Granted, that is a contrived example. So let's consider a couple more involved ideas.

### Mutable reference type

First, there's this one: what if `Integer` were a mutable reference type?

```
class Integer
{
    public int Value;
}
```

Then we could have code like this:

```
class Something
{
    public Integer Integer { get; set; }
}
```

And:

```
Integer x = new Integer { Value = 10 };

Something t1 = new Something();
t1.Integer = x;

Something t2 = new Something();
t2.Integer = t1.Integer;

t1.Integer.Value += 1;

Console.WriteLine(t2.Integer.Value); // Would output 11
```

This seems to defy intuition: that the line `t2.Integer = t1.Integer` would simply copy a value (actually, it does; but that "value" is in fact a reference) and thus that `t2.Integer` would remain independent of `t1.Integer`.

### Mutable value type

This could be approached another way, of course, keeping `Integer` as a value type but maintaining its mutability:

```
struct Integer
{
    public int Value;

    // just for kicks
    public static implicit operator Integer(int value)
    {
        return new Integer { Value = value };
    }
}
```

But now let's say we do this:

```
Integer x = 10;

Something t = new Something();
t.Integer = x;

t.Integer.Value += 1; // This actually won't compile; but if it did,
                      // it would be modifying a copy of t.Integer, leaving
                      // the actual value at t.Integer unchanged.

Console.WriteLine(t.Integer.Value); // would still output 10
```

Basically, immutability of *values* is something that is **highly intuitive**. The opposite is highly unintuitive.

I guess that is subjective, though, in all fairness ;)

Comment: Nice improvements in your last edit. If I could upvote a second time (in what is called Chicago style), I would.

Comment: It occurs to me that Java has an `int` primitive that is not an object as well as an `Integer` primitive wrapper class. This means that your contrived examples aren't really all that contrived. :-)

Comment: Consider a real struct type like "Rectangle".  Which is clearer: "someRect.Width *= 2;" or "someRect = someRect.withNewWidth(someRect.Width*2);"  It's too bad .net provides such feeble support for mutable value-type properties, but often times mutable value-type semantics are much cleaner than anything else.

Comment: @supercat: I'm kind of halfway on this one. I certainly agree that mutable value types are not bad per se. I find uses for them quite often, in fact. The unfortunate fact, however, is that they can be tricky even for smart developers. Take your example: `someRect.Width *= 2;` does indeed seem nice and clear; but then make that a property and suddenly the code doesn't work: `someObject.Rectangle.Width *= 2;` Of course, the latter won't compile; but unfortunately this would (assuming the method existed): `someObject.Rectangle.Scale(2);` As with all things, there are arguments on both sides.

Comment: @Dan Tao: I consider .net to have a few weaknesses in its handling of value types: (1) no "const ref" parameters, nor a means of distinguishing which struct methods modify "this"; (2) no support for any type of property other than a read accessor, a write accessor, or a (read-accessor/write-accessor) pair.  I think all of the "problems" with mutable structs boil down to those two things.  Given #1, btw, I would agree that with Eric Lippert that structs should almost never mutate "this" within their methods.

Comment: @Dan Tao: If the scale method were "static Rectangle.Scale(ref theRectangle, double Amount);" I don't think anything would compile that shouldn't.  If an extension method could have that signature, it would be usable as an ordinary method when it should be, but refuse to compile when appropriate.  My take on the notion of mutable value types being "evil" is that self-mutating types are "evil" in the context of .net, given that things like boxing, which a struct can't prevent, assume no self-mutation, but otherwise they're not evil--just limited in some contexts.

Comment: @Dan Tao: If I had my druthers, it would be possible for a value-type "property" of type T to be a method with at least one open generic type U [V, W...] which would accept a method that had a ref parameters of type T and U [V, W...] and would call it with an item of type T along with the passed in U [V, W...].  "someObject.theRect.x=someInteger" would translate into "someObject.theRect__invoker<Integer>(ref someInteger, (ref theRect, ref param1)=>{theRect.x = param1;}". Passing value types by reference is very performant. The one problem is that the number of ref parameters needed would vary.

Comment: I tried the last example with mutable value type and the output was 11, as I thought it would. It has been many years, but I don't think this would have changed since then.

Answer (score 10):

Integer variables *are* mutable. However, integer literals are constants, hence immutable.

```
int i = 0;

// Mutation coming!
i += 3;

// The following line will not compile.
3 += 7;
```

It's possible to *make* an integer field immutable, using `readonly`. Likewise, an integer property could be get-only.

Comment: Thank you for the downvote. Now I would appreciate it if you offered an explanation so that I can learn from my mistake.

Comment: @Robert: Didn't say it was. :-)

Comment: It would be great if someone were to point out the error. Otherwise, I might spend the rest of my life imagining that there's no error here.

Comment: Given the silence and the upvotes, I suspect that the original downvote may have been in error. If that is not the case, I am open to correction.

Comment: The argument isn't "is 3 immutable"... it's "is an integer immutable". Huge difference. i += 3 is the same thing as i = i + 3... it's still immutable. "an immutable object is an object whose state cannot be modified after it is created." You aren't editing i IN PLACE. You are editing it and returning it back into a "new" i. Just like "hello " + "world!" means NOTHING without an s = ... on the left side.

Comment: @WernerCD: Thanks for your response. For something to be immutable, it would have to be initialized to some state that cannot ever change. This clearly applies to an immutable class such as `System.String`, as there is a distinction between the instance and its references. For a struct like `System.Windows.Point`, there is a distinction between replacing the entire thing and just changing a part, so preventing the latter is a type of immutability. However, a `System.Int32` is a value without parts, so there is no distinction possible between wholesale replacement and modification.

Comment: If you declare an `int` field in a class, it is fully mutable, in that it can be changed at will. Not only can you use replacement semantics, such as `_x = 7;`, you can also use modification semantics, like `_x += 7;`. On the other hand, if you make it `readonly`, then neither sort of change is possible. Contrast this with, say, a `System.Text.StringBuilder`, for which `Append` is possible even when the field is `readonly` but replacement is not.

Comment: When there is a distinction between an instance and its references or a whole and its parts, then we can speak of immutability. But the distinction breaks down for self-valued value types, such as the "primitive" numerics. There is no way, even in principle, to answer the question of whether we are modifying the integer or replacing it. Therefore, contrary to what you said, integers are not immutable in any meaningful sense, although they can be made immutable through `readonly` and `const`.

Comment: @StevenSudit I think `Immutable` doesn't mean a variable can be modified or not. It means whether you create a new copy on the memory or just modify the value on the original address. And when you call `int a=5; a=6`, it creates a new value 6 on stack instead of changing the 5 to 6. See [ImmutableList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467165(v=vs.111).aspx) remark, `int` does the same thing.

Comment: I know it's kind of semantics and may have different meaning under different circumstances. But according to Microsoft's [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32?view=netframework-4.7.2) _Int32 is an immutable value type that ......_ and _Members that appear to modify instance state actually return a new instance initialized with the new value_

Comment: @joe The point I made almost a decade ago still stands: there is no principled basis for a distinction between making a new copy of an int and modifying it. It has no identity other than its value, so changing its value necessarily changes its identity.

Answer (score 7):

As a mutable object, you have to lock an `int` variable before you change it (in any multi-threaded code that writes to your int from separate threads).

Why?  Let's say you were incrementing an `int`, like this:

```
myInt++
```

Under the hood, this is a 32-bit number.  Theoretically, on a 32 bit computer you could add 1 to it, and this operation might be atomic; that is, it would be accomplished in one step, because it would be accomplished in a CPU register.  Unfortunately, it's not; there is more going on than this.

What if another thread mutated this number while it was in the middle of being incremented?  Your number would get corrupted.

However, if you make a thread-safe copy of your object before you increment it, operate on your thread-safe copy, and return a new object when your increment is complete, you guarantee that your increment is thread safe; it cannot be affected by any operations on the original object that take place on other threads, because you're no longer working with the original object.  In effect, you have made your object immutable.

This is the basic principle behind functional programming; by making objects immutable, and returning new objects from functions, you get thread safety for free.

Comment: I'm not sure this follows. In fact, the code you show is *not* thread-safe. You would need to use `Interlocked.Increment` to assure that.

Comment: I should also mention that it's impossible to lock an int, since it's not a reference type.

Comment: Thanks for changing your answer, but I'm sorry to have to say that it's still not correct. The `int` variable is mutable, as shown by the fact that you can increment it. And the increment operation, as mentioned, is not atomic. Even though it would normally be implemented as an `INC` opcode, that's not atomic with a `LOCK` prefix. It may be a single opcode, but translates to a fetch and a store, which means another core could win a race by storing in between those two steps.

Comment: @Steven: I never actually say in my answer that `int` is immutable, nor do I say that the increment is atomic, but only that it might be atomic if it were done in one step. The increment is probably not the best example, since it is multi-step anyway (it returns a value, then increments). My point is that you can return a new object and get thread safety, provided you can guarantee that the original object won't mutate during your operation. You can make that guarantee by creating a thread-safe copy of your original object, prior to performing your operation.

Comment: I realize that you're using numerous contrafactuals as part of your explanation, but they don't seem to be clearly identified as false.

Comment: @Steven: I don't know what that means.  The answer says what it says, no more and no less.  I think you're trying to read more into it than is actually there.

Comment: A contrafactual is a conditional known to be false. "If pigs had wings, then bacon would be kosher" is one example. In your answer, you say things like, "If int's were mutable, then we would have to lock them before changing them." The problem is that this isn't correct: int variables *are* mutable, whereas int constants are (like all constants) immutable. Also, we do have to use a lock (or the equivalent) to make changes atomic. Does that help explain my concern?

Comment: Robert, I just want to apologize if I came across as insufficiently clear or excessively picky. My motivation is to make your answer as good as it can be, not to be critical for its own sake.

Answer (score 3):

It makes sense to have `BoundedInt` as a mutable type because it represents a variable that at any point in time has a specific value and that value can be changed but only within a certain range.

However *integers* themselves aren't variables so they should not be mutable.

Answer (score 2):

Anything with value semantics should be immutable in C#.

Mutable classes can't have value semantics because you can't override the assignment operator.

```
MyClass o1=new MyClass();
MyClass o2=o1;
o1.Mutate();
//o2 got mutated too
//=> no value but reference semantics
```

Mutable structs are ugly because you can easily call a mutating method on a temporary variable. In particular properties return temporary variables.

```
MyStruct S1;
MyStruct S2{get;set;}

S1.Mutate(); //Changes S1
S2.Mutate();//Doesn't change S2
```

That's why I don't like that most Vector libraries use mutating methods like Normalize in their Vector struct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on an academic project with Neural Networks. These networks do heavy computation with doubles. I run it on amazon cloud for days on 32 core servers. When profiling the application, the top performance problem is allocation of double!! 
It would be fair to have a dedicated namespace with mutable types. "unsafe" keywords can be enforced for additional precaution.