# C# - Referencing "this int" parameter

Tags: c#, int, bit-manipulation, this, ref

I have very simple Bitwise Operator methods that I want to use like this:

```
myInt.SetBit(int k, bool set)
```

so that it changes the bit at index 'k' to the value 'set' (0 or 1) I first thought of doing it like this:

```
public static void SetBit(this int A, int k, bool set) { 
    if (set) A |= 1 << k; 
    else A &= ~(1 << k); 
}
```

but of course this only changes the internal value of variable 'A', and not the original variable, since integer isn't a reference type.
I can't use 'ref' along with 'this' so I don't know how to turn this into a reference parameter.
I already have similar methods for Int arrays, but those work fine since an array is a reference type.

I'm looking for a way to keep this handy syntax for single integers, if there is one.

Comment: Change your signature from `void` to `int` and return the new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest just *returning* the result instead of trying to change immutable `int`:

```
  // int instead of void
  public static int SetBit(this int A, int k, bool set) { 
    return set ? (A | (1 << k)) : (A & (~(1 << k))); 
  }
```

So you can do

```
  int source = 12345;
  int result = source.SetBit(3, true);
```

Comment: I had multiple answers explaining the best solution in a very short time, I am putting this one as the valid answer because of it being very clear and to the point, as well as the optimized one-line syntax. 
Thanks to everyone who took the time to answer!

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't treat it as a reference type.

Make your method return the modified value and assign it back to your variable. That approach will be consistent to immutable types. Consider example of `String.Replace`, it doesn't modify the string in place, instead it returns a modified copy.

```
public static int SetBit(this int A, int k, bool set)
{
    if (set) A |= 1 << k;
    else A &= ~(1 << k);

    return A;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very quick answer!
It makes a lot of sense, although it changes the syntax to `myInt = myInt.SetBit(parameters)` instead of simply having `myInt.SetBit(parameters)` work by itself. 
I hoped to keep the easy syntax but I figured changing it might be necessary, this sounds like the best solution indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Some types (like `int`s) are immutable, meaning that once they are set to a value, they cannot be changed again. You'll notice that any method working on an `int` will return a new `int` rather than changing the value of the given value.

Update your code like this:

```
public static int SetBit(this int A, int k, bool set) { 
    if (set) A |= 1 << k; 
    else A &= ~(1 << k); 
    return A;
}
```

and use it like:

```
var x = 5;
x = x.SetBit(1, true);
```

Comment: *You'll notice that any method working on an int will return a new int rather than changing the value of the given value* - well, except methods with `ref int` parameters...

Comment: Er, nope. What about `x++`?

Comment: x++ is semantic sugar for x += 1, which is semantic sugar for x = x + 1.

Comment: @Glubus, actually , its not. They behave differently too. apart from that. `++` is operator and not a method.

Comment: You also suggest that `int`s are immutable, may be worth clarifying that statement.

Comment: @DavidG, `int`s are immutable. That statement is [correct](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14009293/961113).

Comment: @Habib Exactly, that's what I mean! OP just says "some types are immutable" but never says that int is.

Comment: Ah I see your point now @DavidG, I'll update accordingly, though you should feel free to edit yourself!

Comment: As for the `x++` call, to my understanding this execution does in fact 'discard' the instance of `int` it works on, by the means of overwriting the memory. This means the integer is not actually mutated, and a new instance of int is created, albeit that no new memory is allocated to store this value.

Answer (score 0):

I had to check on this because it looks a little odd.  Sure enough - you can't write an extension method using `ref`.

[See here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b26eac53-6485-4789-8a6a-80552d08db52/extension-methods-cant-use-ref-and-this-at-the-same-time?forum=csharplanguage), someone else has tried this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix `this` and `ref` in the extension methods. You have many choices:

1. Returning the result from the extension method (I prefer this option):

   ```
   public static int SetBit(this int A, int k, bool set)
   {
       if (set) A |= 1 << k;
       else A &= ~(1 << k);

       return A;
   }
   ```

   using:

   ```
   int i = 3;       
   i = i.SetBit(1, false);
   ```
2. Using a method with `ref`:

   ```
   public static void SetBitRef(ref int A, int k, bool set)
   {
       if (set) A |= 1 << k;
       else A &= ~(1 << k);
   }
   ```

   using:

   ```
       int i = 3;
       IntExtensions.SetBitRef(ref i, 1, false);
   ```
3. Using an IntWrapper class instead of int:

   ```
       class IntWrapper
       {
           public IntWrapper(int intValue)
           {
               Value = intValue;
           }

           public int Value { get; set; }
       }
   ```

   with a reference type you can create this extension method:

   ```
   public static void SetBit(this IntWrapper A, int k, bool set)
   {
       int intValue = A.Value;

       if (set) intValue |= 1 << k;
       else intValue &= ~(1 << k);

       A.Value = intValue;
   }
   ```

   using:

   ```
   IntWrapper iw = new IntWrapper(3);
   iw.SetBit(1, false);
   ```